# How to increase a ProgressBar Value according to the content of TextBoxes?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, progress-bar

So I have 4 TextBoxes and I have already set the maximum value of my ProgressBar to `4`.

```
ProgressAttr.Maximum = 4;
```

What I would like to do is increase my ProgressBar Value by `1` every time I fill out a TextBox.

My code right now looks like this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name_txtBox.Text))
{
    ProgressAttr.Value += 1;
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Serial_TxtBox.Text))
{
    ProgressAttr.Value += 1;
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Cap_TxtBox.Text))
{
    ProgressAttr.Value += 1;
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(IDprk_TxtBox.Text))
{
    ProgressAttr.Value += 1;
}
```

This doesn't increase the value of my ProgressBar.
I've also tried this:

```
if (textbox.Text.Length > 0)
{
      ProgressAttr.Value += 1;
}
```

None of this works for me and Ive been trying to find a solution for hours. I would really appreciate your help and am looking forward to seeing solutions that you guys suggest!

Answer (score 1):

I'm proposing you a method that makes use of DataBindings to synchronize the content of your TextBoxes with the `Value` property of a ProgressBar.

A class object can notify changes related to its Properties values implementing the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://INotifyPropertyChanged) interface. Its public [`PropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged) event is raised to notify bound Controls that Properties of the data Provider have changed.
All bound Properties are then updated to the new values.

This allows you to have all the logic in a single place and changes to the User Interface (your Form, here) do not affect the data binding in any way.
You can add or remove Controls from the UI. The binding procedure doesn't change or needs to keep track of what has changed in the UI.

For example, bind your **`ProgressBar.Value`** property to the **`ProgressBarController.Value`** property. You initialize the ProgressBarController with the instances of the TextBox (or RichTextBox) Controls that you want to include, add a Binding to *link* the properties and that's all. All the rest happens automatically.

```
ProgressBarController pbarController = null;

// Form Constuctor
public SomeForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // [...]

    // These TextBoxes could be child of a Container (e.g., a Panel), so you could 
    // also get all the child Controls of this Container to build the array
    var textBoxes = new[]{ Name_txtBox, Serial_TxtBox, Cap_TxtBox, IDprk_TxtBox}
    ProgressAttr.Maximum = textBoxes.Length;

    pbarController = new ProgressBarController(textBoxes);
    ProgressAttr.DataBindings.Add("Value", pbarController, "Value", false, 
        DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
}

protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    pbarController.Dispose();
    base.OnFormClosed(e);
}
```

[image: ProgressBar DataBindings]

<sub>Here, two TextBoxes already contain some text when the Form is loaded, so the ProgressBar shows a progress. If you remove all text in the Designer, of course the progress shown is initially `0`:</sub>

---

The `ProgressBarController` class is initialized with the array of Controls passed in its Contructor.

► It then build a `Dictionary<TextBoxBase, int>` to keep track of the progress value associated to a Control: `0` if its Text is empty, otherwise `1`.
<sub>[TextBoxBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase) so you can also use RichTextBox Controls.</sub>

► The `TextChanged` event of these Controls is subscribes to using a single handler. The **`sender`** object will be the Control that raised the event.

► If/when the associated value has changed (the Control Text state determines a change), the `PropertyChanged` event is raised and the DataBinding notifies the ProgressBar to update its `Value` property.

► When the Parent Form is closed, call the `Dispose()` method of this class to remove the subscription to the `TextChanged` events.

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

private class ProgressBarController : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private Dictionary<TextBoxBase, int> states;
    private int m_Value = 0;

    public ProgressBarController(params TextBoxBase[] tboxes) {
        states = new Dictionary<TextBoxBase, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < tboxes.Length; i++) {
            states.Add(tboxes[i], tboxes[i].Text.Length > 0 ? 1 : 0);
            tboxes[i].TextChanged += TextChanged;
        }
        m_Value = states.Values.Sum();
    }

    public int Value {
        get => m_Value;
        private set {
            if (value != m_Value) {
                m_Value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    protected void TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var tbx = sender as TextBoxBase;
        int state = tbx.Text.Length > 0 ? 1 : 0;
        if (states[tbx] != state) {
            states[tbx] = state;
            Value = states.Values.Sum();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        foreach (var tb in states.Keys) {
            tb.TextChanged -= this.TextChanged;
        }
    }
}
```